# mysterious error 1064

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to inserting a string into MySQL db - it contains regular expressions containing quotes,asterisks,backslashes etc - the following isn't working - any thoughts how to correct it? I have also tried htmlentities with no joy based on other answers.

```
qa_db_query_sub('INSERT INTO `^islamiqa_topics` (title, description, regexp) VALUES ($, $, $)', $title, $description, mysql_real_escape_string($regexp));
```

This is the error I get:

```
Database query error 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regexp) 
VALUES ('7/7', '3rd of March 1924 was the day the Ottoman' at line 1

INSERT INTO `qa_islamiqa_topics` (title, description, regexp) VALUES ('7/7', '3rd of March 1924 was the day the Ottoman Caliphate was formally abolished in Turkey by Mustafa Kemal Atataurk.', '7/7(/2005)?|7(th)? july 2005|july 7.* 2005')
```

Comment: Use parameters to insert values into the database.

Comment: What client language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base64_encode() the string before adding to database.

```
qa_db_query_sub('INSERT INTO `islamiqa_topics` (`title`, `description`, `regexp`) VALUES ($, $, $)', $title, $description, base64_encode($regexp));
```

Also, @Del found out that regexp is a reserved word, so you cannot use it as a table column name. You may also try to use `regexp` (add quotes)

Comment: I edited my answer, please try again, there was a ^ character before the table name

Comment: Same problem... the table names are preceded by qa_ hence the need for ^

Comment: I've just spotted the problem - regexp is a reserved word

Comment: Thanks for your reply - which would also have worked which is why I have upvoted it - if you include the answer into it I can select it as the answer too.